# Kongregate API (Unity WebGL C#): What happens with the user data if the player is not using an account?

Tags: c#, unity-webgl, kongregate

I am interested solely in what happens with the userinfo if a player is not signed into their Kongregate, I need to check for this as I will be saving game progress on a server and of course I don't want to be writing random save records into my database that will never actually be used.

My code is as follows

```
public void OnKongregateAPILoaded(string userInfoString)
{
    var info = userInfoString.Split('|');
    var userId = System.Convert.ToInt32(info[0]);
    var username = info[1];
    var gameAuthToken = info[2];
    Debug.Log("Kongregate User Info: " + username + ", userId: " + userId);
}
```

More specifically what I'm asking for is, will something such as username return null? Or something in general that I can check for?

Comment: Wouldn't this have been easy enough to test?

Comment: I didn't want to publish my game without it being ready, and it needs to be published for me to test it without being signed into an account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Username changes to: "Guest"
Id changes to: 0

Comment: Checking the username and userId to determine this is not officially documented. You should use the [`services.isGuest()`](https://docs.kongregate.com/docs/client-api-services-isguest) method to check this instead. See [handling guests](https://docs.kongregate.com/docs/concepts-handling-guests).

Comment: I didn't even think about adding that to the jslib, thank you